# Pushing value to array that is the value of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following structure:

```
let mappings = {
    "1002": ["1000", "1003"],
    "2000": ["2001", "2002"]
}
```

and I want to add this piece of data

```
const issueTypes = ["4000"]
```

to each of the arrays of the object keys ending with this

```
mappings = {
    "1002": ["1000", "1003", "4000"],
    "2000": ["2001", "2002", "4000"]
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
mappings = Object.keys(mappings).reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
            console.log("prevous", prev)
            console.log("curret", curr)
        return ({
            ...prev, [curr]: //unsure of this part which is kind of crucial
        })}, mappings)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just iterate over the values of the object, and push?

```js
const mappings = {
    "1002": ["1000", "1003"],
    "2000": ["2001", "2002"]
}
const issueTypes = ["4000"]
for (const arr of Object.values(mappings)) {
  arr.push(...issueTypes);
}
console.log(mappings);
```

If it must be done immutably, map the entries of the object to a new array of entries, while spreading the new `issueTypes` into the value.

```js
const mappings = {
    "1002": ["1000", "1003"],
    "2000": ["2001", "2002"]
}
const issueTypes = ["4000"]
const newMappings = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(mappings).map(
    ([key, arr]) => [key, [...arr, ...issueTypes]]
  )
);
console.log(newMappings);
```

Comment: that works a treat, I was trying to use reduce to kind of challenge myself since I have barely used it before, but this is a lot neater, Thanks!

Comment: Mis-using `reduce` is [pretty common](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg). Like an old-fashioned `for` loop, there are quite a few cases where it *can* be used when the same approach can be accomplished with a simpler method. No need to feel that complicated is better.

Comment: completely agree with you, I actually managed to get reduce to work but it was way to complicated when this solution is a lot simpler. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is quite simple. What you need to do is this —

- Iterate over each value of the `mappings` object.
- Push the new value

Refer to the following code and adapt —

```
let mappings = {
    "1002": ["1000", "1003"],
    "2000": ["2001", "2002"]
}

const issueTypes = ["4000"]


for (const item in mappings) {
    mappings[item].push(issueTypes[0])
}
```

Hope this helps! :)